# Matching the variables row by row from Data Set with a list of variables in an other Data frame

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set "ds1" with list of countries, and Data frame with an other list of countries "df1"

The problem is to matching the variables row by row from "ds1" with a list of variables in Data frame "df1" and get a column with the result.

So desirable output would be :

```
df1 <- c("BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK")
ds1 <- data.frame(c.id = c("US","BG","CZ","DK","CA","EE","IE","NZ","GR","FR","HR","IT"))

> ds1
   c.id
1    US
2    BG
3    CZ
4    DK
5    CA
6    EE
7    IE
8    NZ
9    GR
10   FR
11   HR
12   IT


> df1
 [1] "BE" "BG" "CZ" "DK" "DE" "EE" "IE" "EL" "ES" "FR" "HR" "IT" "CY" "LV" "LT" "LU" "HU" "MT" "NL" "AT" "PL" "PT" "RO" "SI" "SK" "FI" "SE" "UK"
```

and desirable output would be some like :

```
> ds1
   c.id   match
1    US   FALSE
2    BG   TRUE
3    CZ   TRUE
4    DK   TRUE
5    CA   FALSE
6    EE   TRUE
7    IE   TRUE
8    NZ   FALSE
9    GR   TRUE
10   FR   TRUE
11   HR   TRUE
12   IT   TRUE
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `ds1$c.id %in% df1`

Comment: Shouldn't `GR` in your output be "FALSE" ?

Comment: a more crazy way with warning  could be     duplicated(ds1) | duplicated(df1)

Comment: Warning message:
In duplicated(ds1) | duplicated(df1) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: > res<-grepl(paste(df1, collapse = "|"), ds1$c.id)
> res
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         Does the job but in different format

Comment: > ds1$match <- ds1$c.id %in% df1
> ds1
   c.id match
1    US FALSE
2    BG  TRUE
3    CZ  TRUE
4    DK  TRUE
5    CA FALSE
6    EE  TRUE
7    IE  TRUE
8    NZ FALSE
9    GR FALSE
10   FR  TRUE
11   HR  TRUE
12   IT  TRUE               Perfect solution   Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ds1$match <- ds1$c.id %in% df1
ds1
```